# Ошибка 404 на сайте, хотя он отображается и работает корректно

Tags: javascript, html, .net, битрикс

Всем привет, такая проблема. что на моем сайте все работает и отображается корректно, но в консоли разработчика браузера пишет ошибка 404, из-за этого google page speed говорит, что сайта нет

```
GET https://cheboksary.go495.ru/ 404
```

Как это исправить? Сайт написан на **bitrix**

> C файлом .htaccess все в порядке

Но на всякий случай кину его

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

  #php_value display_errors 1

  #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/(.*)$

  RewriteRule (^|.*?/)index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !http(s|)://
  RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index.htm$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index.html$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Если смотреть код элемента, то там такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно почему такой ответ сервера. Это точно ответ при запросе html, а не ресурсов(картинки, шрифты и т.п.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У какого-то из компонент на странице стоит настройка `SET_STATUS_404 = "Y"`. Поэтому когда этот компонент не находит требуемый раздел или элемент, он выставляет статус 404.

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog.php

Comment: Спасибо, друг!!! Действительно помогло!)

Comment: В таком случае, отметь ответ как принятый.

Comment: Как это сделать?)

Comment: @Dima используйте **галочку ✓** слева от вопроса